# How do I mock S3Object.read do |chunk| using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, rspec, streaming

I'm new to ruby and rspec.
I have a module that interacts with S3 in ruby.
In my code I :

1. create a new S3 instance : s3 =  AWS::S3.new()
2. Get my bucket : @s3bucket = s3.buckets[@bucket]
3. Retrieve my S3Object : object = @s3bucket.objects[key]
4. Finally, I save the object to a local file:

   ```
   File.open(local_filename, 'wb') do |s3file|
   object.read do |chunk|
     return completed if stop?
     s3file.write(chunk)
   end
   ```

My code works well, but I'm having problems unit testing it,
 
specifically I'm having problems mocking the object.read do |chunk| part.
No matter what I try the chunk turns out empty.
Can some one help?
Thanks.

Comment: I found this gem:  https://github.com/jubos/fake-s3.  If you want to manually mock it, just put a binding.pry or byebug debugger in your method and figure out the class and the content of the S3 object.  Then do allow_any_instance_of(<the S3 class>).to receive(<method you are calling on it>).and_return(<the return value of your method>)

Comment: I tried that, I think I have a problem understanding the object to return in the and_return part. tried string, stringio, byte array, File.open. nothing worked. in my test I still get no chunks and the s3file is empty

Comment: See my answer below and let me know if you have any questions.  I would have put it in a comment but there is no code formatting option that way.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
s3_object = class_double("S3Object")
allow(s3_object).to receive(:read).and_return(<what ever you want>)
```

If you need to need to store API responses in your tests without making multiple calls, check out https://github.com/vcr/vcr

Comment: since when? and what replaced it?

Comment: OK, and if I  don't have access to the s3_object? tried allow(AWS::S3::S3Object.any_instance).to receive(:read).and_yield('test'), didn't work

Comment: which rails version are you on?  It should be allow_any_instance_of(AWS::S3).to_receive(:read).and_return(<the return value of the method>)

Comment: why not : allow(AWS::S3::S3Object.any_instance).to receive(:read).and_yield('boaz')? the object is of type S3Object

Comment: in the beginning of the code I wrote AWS.stub! , could this cause a problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mock this:

```
create a new S3 instance : s3 = AWS::S3.new()
```

you do

```
allow_any_instance_of(AWS::S3).to_receive(:new).and_return(<the return value of the method>)
```

You can use VCR as suggested previously but you will run into issues if you are working on a team and you run your tests at the same time as another team member if you both have deleted the same cassette.